# License issue connecting to on premise DB2 ZoS

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway, dataworks, dataconnect

Even after connection is established (with secure gateway and client on my computer through which I can access the DB) and schema and tables selected in dataworks and either refine or copy selected the error below appears:

> The IBM Data Server for JDBC and SQLJ license was invalid ; or was not activated for the DB2 for z/OS subsystem. If you are connecting directly to ; the data server and using DB2 Connect Unlimited Edition for System z, perform the ; activation step by running the activation program in the license activation kit. ; If you are using any other edition of DB2 Connect, obtain the license file, ; db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar, from the license activation kit, and follow the installation ; directions to include the license file in the class path.

I do have `db2jcc.jar` files on my machine, where they would need to be placed?
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar on your machine as well? How are you connecting to Secure Gateway/DB2? Are you using WebSphere Application Server for example?

Comment: Hi, yes I do have file on the machine. So far I have IBM SG client on my machine running and allowing bluemix secure gateway connect to private network trough my machine. What it is hard to understand, after connecting in dataworks I am able to select schemas and tables, even preview them, however, when refine or run selected error appears. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to narrow down where the issue could lie. I understand you are able to access the schema and selected tables. Secure Gateway software does not natively run on z/OS. Do you install the Secure Gateway client software on a (virtual or physical) Linux or Windows system or use a DataPower Gateway to establish secure connectivity between Bluemix and your environment?

Comment: Hi, I have client  installed on Windows system (runs as a black screen in the background). In addition we use IBM DB2 to access the data sources from our machines (any manipulation needed there?) . Thanks

Comment: I understand. How are is your application connecting to the DataWorks -> SG -> DB2 z/OS flow? Is it a Java application running locally or an application deployed to public Bluemix?

Comment: It is no application so far.. All I am trying to do is to get the data from local DB2 and copy to DashDB (after some data manipulation), and keep on doing it on scheduled basis (as DataWorks allows it). Later the application will be using Dash DB.